# freetds ./configure unrecognized option --prefix

Tags: make

I'm trying to compile freetds according to these instructions: http://www.mavrick.id.au/2012/php-5-3-6-mssql-freetds/

However configure is failing. My command is:

```
./configure --enable-msdblib -–prefix=/usr/local/freetds
```

I'm getting

```
configure: error: unrecognized option: `-–prefix=/usr/local/freetds'
Try `./configure --help' for more information.
```

for all command line options, even --help

I have build-essentials, gcc and make installed. I also tried sudo, even though I am logged in as root. It seems to me something is still missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `--prefix` ("minus minus"), not `-–prefix` ("minus dash")

Answer (score 1):

You've copy-pasted the command from a webpage and, if you look closely, you've got a funny character instead of one of the dashes in `--prefix`.

Just type it in manually :)